# Getting the name and other properties of SPAlbum

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Just a quick question about SPTrack and SPAlbum

Say I have an array of SPTracks stored in myTracks

I can get the name of this track by doing

```
[[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] name];
```

However; when I try to get the name of the album like this

```
[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] album];
```

an SPAlbum object is returned.  This makes sense, but I am unable to access the name property of the SPAlbum like so:

```
[[[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] album] name];
```

The name property is defined as an NSString in SPAlbum.m.  Am I attempting to access this incorrectly?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting `nil` back?

If so, you need to make sure your objects are loaded first, using `SPAsyncLoading`.

```
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:[[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] album] timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {

    if (loadItems.count == 0) return; // Album didn't load!

    NSLog(@"%@", [[[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] album] name]);
}];
```

Comment: So a couple of issues make me think I'm going about this wrong.  When I try `[[[myTracks objectAtIndex:0] album] name]` I get syntax error "Bad receiver type sp_album *"  When I try to do this using the artists name, I can access it like `[[[myTracks objectatIndex:0] artist] name]`, but I get runtime error "-[SPTrack artist]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5986d0"

Comment: The first one happens when you send the `-album` selector to an `SPAlbum` object - make sure your array really only contains tracks. The second one occurs because `SPTrack` doesn't have an `artist` property - it has an array of `artists`.